# making a request using AFXMLRequestOperation in AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, ios

After changing server to ssl ( http --> https ), I'm getting failure block executed and generating the error such as

> request timed out

I know AFXMLRequestOperation is subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperation which is a subclass of AFURLConnectionOperation for requests using the HTTP or HTTPS protocols. Therefore, I thought I could get some response back from server,  not the above error .

Does anybody experience it before, please help. Any comments are welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the ssl certificate you're using on your server is self signed or is not signed by a suitable certificate authority.  I would start by investigating that, and then take steps to force your app to connect to the server even though the certificate is abnormally signed.